# Is there an easy way to reduce the number of colors in an IndexedColorModel?

Tags: java, image-processing, png, javax.imageio

I have a large 8-bit PNG image.  I am using Java to slice the image into smaller 32x32 images.  I use Java's `ImageIO` to load the PNG into a `BufferedImage` and then call it's `getSubimage(x, y, 32, 32)`.  I then use `ImageIO` to write each tile out as a PNG.

The problem is that the resulting image has the same `IndexColorModel` as the original image.  For example, one 32x32 tile has only 8 total colors but it includes a color model with all 100-odd colors from the original image.

I would like to remove unused colors from the 32x32 tile's `IndexColorModel` before I write out the PNG.  There is no sense including color data for colors not used in the image and I'd like the images to be as small as possible.

Is there a built-in mechanism to do this or can someone point me to an (easy) way to modify/reduce the `ColorModel`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `ColorConvertOp` in java.awt.image.

Basically, you create a new `IndexColorModel` of the desired depth. If you really want the smallest, you can walk through the `Raster` and count the colors. Otherwise, just choose 4 or 5 bits per pixel. Then create a `BufferedImage` with `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY` and the `IndexColorMap`. Finally, use the `ColorConvertOp`'s `filter()` method to copy the original data to the new `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Devon, thanks - this got me moving in the right direction except that after creating an `IndexColorModel` with the exact number of colors, the saved PNG still appears to have 256-colors in it's color table.  Either Photoshop is displaying an incorrect color table or the palette has the correct 8 colors and then fills the remaining spaces up to 256 with shades of gray.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, it works for me, so it could be PS is reporting incorrectly. If you're on windows, check the file properties, "Summary" tab, "Advanced". It should show a "Bit Depth" of 4.

Comment: I might have the Bit Depth wrong when I am creating the IndexedColorModel.  It may be in an invalid state which is producing the strangeness in the color table.  I'll check it out and report back here.

Comment: After a bit of experimenting, it looks like 2-color and 8-color work correctly, but 4-color gives me 32-bits/pixel. So, if you have an image with less than 8 colors, pad it out to 8

Comment: It looks like I've been chasing a Photoshop "bug."  Saving the same image out of Photoshop and loading it back in using a custom palette shows the same custom colors and grayscale-padded color table.  Java's ImageIO-encoded PNG is substantially smaller (nearly 40% smaller) than Photoshops but displays properly in browsers and Flash.  Padding was not required in the end - with less than 8 or more than 8 colors, the image in Photoshop still has the grayscale palette (at no extra cost) which actually may be a feature of the PNG format rather than a bug in Photoshop.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: P.S. I'd vote your answer up but I can't because I don't have enough reputation apparently.  Thanks anyway!