# Java Amount Of Colors Lower

Tags: java, image, colors, bufferedimage

I Currently have 256 colors on my BufferedImage but I need to set that to 200 Colors.
Does anyone knows a Java code that sets the image to 200 Colors instead of 256 Colors?

Comment: What's this even mean?  Can you just use 200 of the 256 colors available?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is an odd question because 200 is such a strange number to limit the colors of an image to. I mean, which of the 200 colors would you select, and how would you select them? In other words, how do you eliminate 56 colors?

Comment: A standard image has 256 colors but you can change them with a program like Photoshop. As you can see in this image http://imgur.com/hbX5VjM but I want my Java Program to do this, because it's way easier to use then Photoshop.

Comment: Why you want to change it? What results you expect?

Comment: *"I want my Java Program to do this, because it's way easier to use then Photoshop."*  By the time your app. can do what PhotoShop does, I doubt it will be easy to use either.

Comment: You don't understand it, It's one small feature and I don't need all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you need to take a look at [ColorConvertOp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html) in java.awt.image. I never used it, but according to [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836199/is-there-an-easy-way-to-reduce-the-number-of-colors-in-an-indexedcolormodel) [resources](http://www.coderanch.com/t/346023/GUI/java/reduce-color-palette-image) it's the way to go.

Alternatively, you can call ImageMagick from Java, and use [QuantizeImage](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/quantize.php) function to reduce the number of colors. You can use [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) to call ImageMagick from Java.